# Deleting channels with Discord.NET

Tags: c#, discord.net

I found out how I can create channels using `discord.net` via await.

`Context.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync(names[0],RequestOptions.Default);`

But I couldn't find a way to also delete that channel. So how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

`channel.Delete();`

Should do the trick https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/issues/426

Seems like it was an issue, but no longer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the SocketTextChannel object you can do channel.DeleteAsync()

Answer (score 1):

Hey that should work try that

```
 SocketGuildChannel socketGuildChannel = channel;
 socketGuildChannel.DeleteAsync();
```

By the way if you have SocketMessage you can do that will like so

```
 SocketMessage arg
 if(arg.Channel is SocketGuildChannel){
     SocketGuildChannel channel = arg.Channel as SocketGuildChannel;
     channel.DeleteAsync();
 }
```